# Papers about quantitative association rules in data mining

Tags: data-mining, references, association-rules

I'm writing my diploma thesis about the interaction between warehouse management and data mining (specifically, association rules).

I started the topic data mining by considering Boolean association rules, created by the a-priori algorithm (for example, market basket analysis). Then I found out about quantitative association rules. They consider not only the question 'what is together in the market basket', but also how much of one item is combined with how much of the second and so on.

Maybe the most important author (and even sort of founder) of data mining is Rakesh Agrawal. He wrote a paper ([pdf](http://rakesh.agrawal-family.com/papers/sigmod96qassoc.pdf)) about mining quantitative association rules. After I found that and considered it, I wanted to find newer papers or literature about this topic, because Agrawal released it 1996. I could find only 3-4 papers about quantitative association rules (respectively quantitative data mining) and don't understand why this topic is not discussed more.

Do you know why it is so hard to find any papers considering it? Why aren't there advancement from Agrawal's idea or just didn't I found them?

Also there exists a lot of software for data mining (for example WEKA) but they don't have the opportunity to mine quantitative association rules, only Boolean ones. So I want you to ask, if you know any software for mining quantitative association rules?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @blub85. CV is not a discussion forum, it is intended as a pure Q & A site. I have edited your Q to make it consistent with this. Please make sure it still says what you want it to. I gather your question is *what papers are there on QAR?* Is there a question in the last paragraph? If so, could you edit to clarify it; if not, you may want to delete it. Since you are new here, you may want to read our [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about), which contains information for new users.

Comment: Hey gung! I'm sorry about that! My two questions are: Are there any advancements of the idea explained paper from Agrawal ("Mining quantitative association rules in large relational tables") and the second one: Do exist any software for mining quantitative association rules?! I found a few programs about data mining, but they only can mine boolean association rules.. Thanx for your help, guys!!

Comment: I would like to find more papers like this.  I will let you know if I find one!